# onchange happen even click on white space of selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just trying to add and remove selectbox items using below code,

```
 $('#moveforzero').val("0");  

$('#SelectFeatures').change(function() {

            var oSrc = document.getElementById('SelectFeatures');

            var oDest = document.getElementById('SelectedFeatures');

            var zero = document.getElementsByName('moveforzero')[0].value;


            for (var i = 0; i < oSrc.options.length; i++) {

                var j=parseInt(zero);

                if (oSrc.options[i].selected == true) {

                    oSrc.options[i].disabled=true;
                    var NewOption = new Option();
                    //var selected = oSrc.options[i].value;
                    NewOption.text = oSrc.options[oSrc.options.selectedIndex].text;
                    NewOption.value = oSrc.options[oSrc.options.selectedIndex].value;


                    oDest.options[j] = NewOption;


                    document.getElementsByName('moveforzero')[0].value=j+1;


                }   
            }


        });


$('#SelectedFeatures').change(function(){ 


        var d,f;
        var minuone=document.getElementsByName('moveforzero')[0].value;

            if(parseInt(minuone)>0)
            {

             document.getElementsByName('moveforzero')[0].value=parseInt(minuone)-1;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementsByName('moveforzero')[0].value="0";
            }

    d=$("#SelectedFeatures option:selected").text();
    var len=$("#SelectedFeatures").length;

    var g =$("#SelectedFeatures");

             //d=selectbox.options[(selectbox.selectedIndex)].text;

             var oSrc = document.getElementById('SelectFeatures');


                for (var i = 0; i < oSrc.options.length; i++) {
                    if (oSrc.options[i].disabled==true) {


                        f=oSrc.options[i].text;


                        if(d==f)
                        {
                            oSrc.options[i].disabled=false;
                            for(var i = 0; i <len; i++)
                            {

                                if($("#SelectedFeatures option["+i+"].selected"))
                                {
                jQuery("#SelectedFeatures option[value='"+d+"']").remove();
                                }

                            }
                        }


                    }   
                  }

     });
```

My problem is even items removing when click on white space inside the removing selectbox.

check my fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/Manivasagam/ff5Lp0gv/18/

How to fix this?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to add empty `option`s until the select box appears full (and then only process those that are not empty)?

Comment: Advice: Since you use Jqeury for selection, use it all around your code. Dont use document.getElementById('SelectFeatures');
Rather use:
$("#SelectFeatures")

Comment: @Wexoni i understand you but actually my code is fully jscript only but when i add my code in jfiddle its not work thats why i added some jquery onchange function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to remove option when you select it. Here i solve this using delegate method. refer this  [JSfIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ff5Lp0gv/27/)

```
$('#SelectedFeatures').delegate('option:selected', 'click',function(){ 

        var d,f;
        var minuone=document.getElementsByName('moveforzero')[0].value;

            if(parseInt(minuone)>0)
            {

             document.getElementsByName('moveforzero')[0].value=parseInt(minuone)-1;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementsByName('moveforzero')[0].value="0";
            }

    d=$("#SelectedFeatures option:selected").text();
    var len=$("#SelectedFeatures").length;
    //alert(len);
    var g =$("#SelectedFeatures");
    //alert(d);
             //d=selectbox.options[(selectbox.selectedIndex)].text;

             var oSrc = document.getElementById('SelectFeatures');


                for (var i = 0; i < oSrc.options.length; i++) {
                    if (oSrc.options[i].disabled==true) {


                        f=oSrc.options[i].text;
                        //alert(f);

                        if(d==f)
                        {
                            //alert("if");
                            oSrc.options[i].disabled=false;
                            for(var i = 0; i <len; i++)
                            {
                                //alert('for');

                                if($("#SelectedFeatures option["+i+"].selected"))
                                {
                                    //alert("remove");
                jQuery("#SelectedFeatures option[value='"+d+"']").remove();
                                }
                                // if(selectbox.options[i].selected)
                                 //selectbox.remove(i);
                            }
                        }


                    }   
                  }



     });
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
option {
    display: inline;
}
option:after {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ff5Lp0gv/24/).

Comment: No, i want to display options one by one.

Comment: So please specify your problem. Seems you're the only one who understands, what you want.

Comment: you are almost right in last update but when you click straight below of items white space inside right side item its removing but i want to do only remove when click on right side items.

Comment: This seems to be a Firefox only issue - clicking below the last option will count as click on the last option. I dont think you can change this. In Chrome its working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of the solution by @Ferret:

Add a blank `<option></option>` to the end of your `select` tag and then change the style of the last (blank) option like so:

```
option:last-child {
    display:inline;
    padding:0px;
}
```

You may want to change the style to only apply to that particular select's last item.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ff5Lp0gv/28/)